# Example of an elegant implementation of 'Defensive Copying' of a nullable java.util.Date in a JavaBean's getter/setter implementation?

Tags: java, javabeans, effective-java

Is there an elegant Java implementation of Joshua Bloch's [defensive copying](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2) techniques using the example below?  The nullChecking is really the issue I think, but perhaps there is a much simpler way to achieve defensive copying.

```
   public class Audit {
      private Date dateCompleted;
      ...      
      public Audit() {
        super();
      }

      //defensive copy of dateCompleted
      public final Date getDateCompleted() {
        if (dateCompleted != null){
          return new Date(dateCompleted.getTime());
        }else{
          return null;
        }
      }

      public final void setDateCompleted(Date dateCompleted) {
        if (dateCompleted != null){
          this.dateCompleted = new Date(dateCompleted.getTime());
        }else{
          this.dateCompleted = null;
        }
      }
      ...
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can have a convenience method in a utility class:

```
public class DateUtils {
    public static Date defensiveCopy(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : new Date(date.getTime());
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public final void setDateCompleted(Date dateCompleted) {
    this.dateCompleted = DateUtils.defensiveCopy(dateCompleted);
}
```

Static imports can hide the `DateUtils` part if you want.

Alternatively, you can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which mostly uses immutable types and is a much better API in general :)

Comment: I was looking in apache commons DateUtils for this method - which led to me posting the question.

Comment: @Brian: You might want to change to another name for your own utility class then :) I would really recommend the Joda Time option if you *possibly* can though...